# Hive ERROR:metastore.RetryingRawStore: JDO datastore error. Retrying metastore command after 1000 ms (attempt 1 of 1)

Tags: hadoop, hive, sybase

I am running Sybase as metastore for my Hive .
I have given proper permission on the database.
But facing issues while performing basic commands .(show tables)

Here is the output of job in debug mode :

```
14/05/27 08:00:59 DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName = com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
14/05/27 08:00:59 DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName = XXX
14/05/27 08:00:59 DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.validateColumns = false
14/05/27 08:00:59 DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.cache.level2 = false
14/05/27 08:00:59 DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.plugin.pluginRegistryBundleCheck = LOG
14/05/27 08:00:59 DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.cache.level2.type = none
14/05/27 08:00:59 DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass = org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory
14/05/27 08:00:59 DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.autoCreateSchema = false
14/05/27 08:00:59 DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.storeManagerType = rdbms
14/05/27 08:00:59 DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.connectionPoolingType = BONECP
14/05/27 08:00:59 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
14/05/27 08:00:59 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
14/05/27 08:00:59 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore.     hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 0.12.0
 14/05/27 08:00:59 ERROR metastore.RetryingRawStore: JDO datastore error. Retrying metastore command after 1000 ms (attempt 1 of 1)
 14/05/27 08:01:02 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 0.12.0
 14/05/27 08:01:04 ERROR exec.DDLTask: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate o    rg.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1043)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)`

Caused by: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Exception thrown obtaining schema column information from datastore
NestedThrowables:
java.sql.SQLException: The 'CREATE TABLE' command is not allowed within a multi-statement transaction in the 'tempdb' database.

    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:451)
```

Comment: Which is your `OS`? If it's `Linux`, then check whether `SeLinux` is enabled. You can do that by the issuing `sestatus` in Terminal.

Comment: How metastore error is related to OS ?
For your info SeLinux is currently disabled .

Comment: AFAIK, there used to be a problem with metastore when SELinux was enabled. But since it's disabled in your case, I take it that it's not SELinux which is causing the problem.

Comment: But you mentioned you're running a `SHOW TABLES`, but the last lines of the error message says `CREATE TABLE`. By default, `ddl in tran` is set to `False`. I haven't used `Sybase` with `Hive`, but this error can be overridden by either setting `ddl in tran` to `True` (which is not a recommended option) or by moving out the DDL from the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You might have one(more) of the following issues :

1.) Please check whether you put the right connector jar in the hive lib for SyBase ?

2.) Your SyBase server is running ?

3.) Did you put correct username/password/connection URL in the hive-site.xml ?

Hope this helps..!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error.. and it could be due to Hive Metastore (HMS) not being able to come up. You may want to restart the HMS service which worked for me. hope this helps..!!

Comment: Please, try to edit appearance of this post and add more details about the procedure you used.